# AFTER PHP-FFMpeg not converting (error with ffmpeg)

Tags: php, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I have installed ffmpeg server side with all the dependencies, updated it. And then installed PHP-FFMpeg with Composer. Tested that ffmpeg is instaled with a ssh conexion.

```
root@host [/opt/ffmpeg]# ffmpeg
ffmpeg version N-81322-ge8b355a Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)
configuration: --disable-yasm
libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
libavcodec     57. 51.100 / 57. 51.100
libavformat    57. 46.100 / 57. 46.100
libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
libavfilter     6. 51.100 /  6. 51.100
libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options]     outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'
```

But when I try to convert a video file with a php script it throws me a very long error.
PHP Code:

```
<?PHP
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/vendors/install/vendor/autoload.php");
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
$video = $ffmpeg->open($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/resources/uploads/96048/ffd3c5e349fa5745159deef163b5c253.wmv');
$video
       ->filters()
       ->synchronize();
$format = new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264();
$format->on('progress', function ($video, $format, $percentage) {
    echo "$percentage % transcoded";});
$video
      ->save($format,$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/resources/uploads/96048/ffd3c5e349fa5745159deef163b5c253.mp4');
?>
```

Error displayed:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Alchemy\BinaryDriver\Exception\ExecutionFailureException' with message 'ffmpeg failed to execute command '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg' '-y' '-i' '/home/user/working/resources/uploads/23097/2efeb41a1a7085a1dbd469c4895ac23e.wmv' '-async' '1' '-metadata:s:v:0' 'start_time=0' '-threads' '12' '-vcodec' 'libx264' '-acodec' 'libfaac' '-b:v' '1000k' '-refs' '6' '-coder' '1' '-sc_threshold' '40' '-flags' '+loop' '-me_range' '16' '-subq' '7' '-i_qfactor' '0.71' '-qcomp' '0.6' '-qdiff' '4' '-trellis' '1' '-b:a' '128k' '-pass' '1' '-passlogfile' '/tmp/ffmpeg-passes57ad320a1b685j794u/pass-57ad320a1b716' '/home/user/working/resources/uploads/23097/2efeb41a1a7085a1dbd469c4895ac23e.mp4'' in /home/user/working/vendors/install/vendor/alchemy/binary-driver/src/Alchemy/BinaryDriver/ProcessRunner.php:100↵Stack trace:↵#0 /home/user/working/vendors/install/vendor/alchemy/binary-driver/src/Alchemy/BinaryDriver/ProcessRunner.php(72): Alchemy\BinaryDriver\ProcessRunner-&gt;doExecutionFailure(''/usr/bin/ffmpe...')↵#1 / in <b>/home/user/working/vendors/install/vendor/php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg/src/FFMpeg/Media/Video.php</b> on line <b>168</b><br />↵"
```

Then I have took the basic code displayed upwards and ran it directly through ssh.

```
'/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg' '-y' '-i' '/home/user/working/resources/uploads/23097/2efeb41a1a7085a1dbd469c4895ac23e.wmv' '-async' '1' '-metadata:s:v:0' 'start_time=0' '-threads' '12' '-vcodec' 'libx264' '-acodec' 'libfaac' '-b:v' '1000k' '-refs' '6' '-coder' '1' '-sc_threshold' '40' '-flags' '+loop' '-me_range' '16' '-subq' '7' '-i_qfactor' '0.71' '-qcomp' '0.6' '-qdiff' '4' '-trellis' '1' '-b:a' '128k' '-pass' '1' '-passlogfile' '/tmp/ffmpeg-passes57ad320a1b685j794u/pass-57ad320a1b716' '/home/user/working/resources/uploads/23097/2efeb41a1a7085a1dbd469c4895ac23e.mp4'
```

And this is the response I get:

```
ffmpeg version N-81322-ge8b355a Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)
  configuration: --disable-yasm
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 51.100 / 57. 51.100
  libavformat    57. 46.100 / 57. 46.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 51.100 /  6. 51.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, asf, from '/home/user/working/resources/uploads/23097/2efeb41a1a7085a1dbd469c4895ac23e.wmv':
  Metadata:
    SfOriginalFPS   : 299700
    WMFSDKVersion   : 11.0.6001.7000
    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
    comment         : Footage: Small World Productions, Inc; Tourism New Zealand | Producer: Gary F. Spradling | Music: Steve Ball
    title           : Wildlife in HD
    copyright       : © 2008 Microsoft Corporation
    IsVBR           : 0
    DeviceConformanceTemplate: AP@L3
  Duration: 00:00:30.09, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6977 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: wmav2 (a[1][0][0] / 0x0161), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: vc1 (Advanced) (WVC1 / 0x31435657), yuv420p, 1280x720, 5942 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
Unknown encoder 'libx264'
```

My question is what to do next? I have wasted 3 days to make this work and this is the furthest I have come. How can I test if libx264 is installed corectly? And if it is not installed corectly how cand I reinstal or make it work?

**After a few modifications**

I have used an already installed ffmpeg, and removed a few commands (that were by default the same) and this time I used only the command line.

**The request**

```
'/home/user/working/vendors/install/ffmpeg-git-20160813-64bit-static/ffmpeg' '-y' '-i' '/home/user/working/resources/uploads/96048/ffd3c5e349fa5745159deef163b5c253.wmv' '-async' '1' '-metadata:s:v:0' 'start_time=0' '-vcodec' 'libx264' '-c:a' 'aac' '-b:v' '1000k' '-b:a' '128k' '-pass' '1' '-passlogfile' '/tmp/ffmpeg-passes57b053ce14a12ljm8a/pass-57b053ce14ad3' '/home/user/working/resources/uploads/96048/ffd3c5e349fa5745159deef163b5c253.mp4'
```

**The new result:**

```
ffmpeg version N-81328-gceab04f-static http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.1 (Debian 5.4.1-1) 20160803
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libwebp --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libfreetype --enable-fontconfig --enable-libxvid --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-gray --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libass --enable-gnutls --enable-libvidstab --enable-libsoxr --enable-frei0r --enable-libfribidi --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --enable-librtmp --enable-libmfx --enable-libzimg --cc=gcc-5
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 51.102 / 57. 51.102
  libavformat    57. 46.101 / 57. 46.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 51.100 /  6. 51.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, asf, from '/home/user/working/resources/uploads/96048/ffd3c5e349fa5745159deef163b5c253.wmv':
  Metadata:
    SfOriginalFPS   : 299700
    WMFSDKVersion   : 11.0.6001.7000
    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
    comment         : Footage: Small World Productions, Inc; Tourism New Zealand | Producer: Gary F. Spradling | Music: Steve Ball
    title           : Wildlife in HD
    copyright       : © 2008 Microsoft Corporation
    IsVBR           : 0
    DeviceConformanceTemplate: AP@L3
  Duration: 00:00:30.09, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6977 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: wmav2 (a[1][0][0] / 0x0161), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: vc1 (Advanced) (WVC1 / 0x31435657), yuv420p, 1280x720, 5942 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
-async is forwarded to lavfi similarly to -af aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0.
[libx264 @ 0x442f5c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x442f5c0] ratecontrol_init: can't open stats file
Output #0, mp4, to '/home/user/working/resources/uploads/96048/ffd3c5e349fa5745159deef163b5c253.mp4':
  Metadata:
    SfOriginalFPS   : 299700
    WMFSDKVersion   : 11.0.6001.7000
    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
    comment         : Footage: Small World Productions, Inc; Tourism New Zealand | Producer: Gary F. Spradling | Music: Steve Ball
    title           : Wildlife in HD
    copyright       : © 2008 Microsoft Corporation
    IsVBR           : 0
    DeviceConformanceTemplate: AP@L3
    Stream #0:0(eng): Unknown: none
    Metadata:
      start_time      : 0
      encoder         : Lavc57.51.102 libx264
    Stream #0:1(eng): Unknown: none
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.51.102 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (vc1 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (wmav2 (native) -> aac (native))
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Comment: Before the ffmpeg update the error was that the command ` -metadata:s:v:0 ` was not recognised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No x264 support

Your `ffmpeg` was not compiled to support encoding via libx264: it is missing `--enable-gpl --enable-libx264` in the configure line. The easiest fix is to [download an already compiled `ffmpeg` binary](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) and point your script to it.

### Other stuff

Your `ffmpeg` has `--disable-yasm`. This is bad and will make things slow.

Your command is a mess and looks like something from 2006. You should be using the [x264 encoding presets](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#a2.Chooseapreset) instead of attempting to declare a legion of options. Remove `-refs`, `-coder`, `-sc_threshold`, `-flags +loop`, `-me_range`, `-subq`, `-i_qfactor`, `-qcomp`, `-qdiff`, and `-trellis` because these are automatically dealt with by default.

It is better to allow this encoder to automatically choose the appropriate number of threads, so remove `-threads 12`.

There is talk that libfaac support is going to be removed from FFmpeg. Your command uses `-acodec libfaac` but your `ffmpeg` was not compiled to support it. There are better alternatives, such as libfdk_aac or the native FFmpeg AAC encoder (`-c:a aac`).

Comment: These commands that you said to remove are automaticaly made by php-ffmpeg how can I make the program to exclude this commands?

Comment: @MagureanDanSergiu I don't know. Maybe you can edit the source or just use the `ffmpeg` cli tool directly. But all of that is extra: this answer addresses the original question regarding `Unknown encoder 'libx264'`. I recommend asking a new question if you want to figure out how to modify what php-ffmpeg does.

Comment: Tried your way, with the already compiled ffmpeg binary and now I get an error with libfaac instead of libx264

Comment: At first when I installed ffmpeg, the libfaac had errors and I couldn't install it. Is that why I have this error now?

Comment: @MagureanDanSergiu Your script is attempting to use libfaac, but the `ffmpeg` you downloaded does not support libfaac because it is considered non-free and therefore non-redistributable. Edit the script and remove any reference of libfaac and use the native AAC encoder instead (`-acodec aac`). Anyway, libfaac support is going to be removed from FFmpeg very soon. Also, do you even need to use an outdated PHP wrapper for `ffmpeg`? Why not use ffmpeg directly? See [FFmpeg Wiki: PHP](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/PHP).

Comment: Tried with `'/home/user/working/vendors/install/ffmpeg-git-20160813-64bit-static/ffmpeg' '-y' '-i' '/home/user/working/resources/uploads/96048/ffd3c5e349fa5745159deef163b5c253.wmv' '-async' '1' '-metadata:s:v:0' 'start_time=0' '-vcodec' 'libx264' '-c:a' 'aac' '-b:v' '1000k' '-b:a' '128k' '-pass' '1' '-passlogfile' '/tmp/ffmpeg-passes57b053ce14a12ljm8a/pass-57b053ce14ad3' '/home/user/working/resources/uploads/96048/ffd3c5e349fa5745159deef163b5c253.mp4'` and the result was: `Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height`

Comment: @MagureanDanSergiu There is missing information. You need to show the complete output and not just a section. You can use a pastebin site and provide the link or add the info to your question.